# Javascript get form value in URL without jQuery

Tags: php, html, ajax, forms, post

If data is submitted via POST through the classic HTML form method is it possible to access those values using standard Javascript without libraries? How would this be done?

Edit for clarity: The variables have been posted. I am trying to access those values via javascript.

Comment: As discussed below, it's not really feasible without a library - but you could attach a function to your form's `onsubmit` event and inside that grab the form values you require at the moment the form is submitted.

Comment: posted my "answer", how bad is it?

Comment: Do you mean "Catch the form before it's submitted" or "Receive a posted form"? The former is possible client side, the latter isn't.

Comment: Receive the posted form. And I managed it? Though I don't know if my solution is "valid". It is however, functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking outside the box: (A hack that should never see the light of day)

For this example the posted variable is "a":

```
var val=document.URL;
var start;
start = val.search(/a=/);
var end;
end = val.search(/&/);
var thispos = val.substring(start+2,end);
```

1. `document.URL` returns the url of the current site.
2. `val.search` returns the position of the first occurrence of the regular expression in
   the parameter field.
3. `substring` the two and...
4. `thispos` now contains the posted variable.

Brutal but functional. Is this too terrible to be an answer?

Comment: More simply:

var data = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");

will give you an array of strings in the format "name=value"

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var myField = document.getElementById('myFieldId');
```

then myField.value will contain the value.

Answer (score 0):

After a post, the data is send to the server, javascript cant do anything with that since its client side. What you can do is pre-check with `document.getElementById('formid')` and use those values in the form. After validating or doing what you want to do, end with `form.submit()` to really send it to the server.

Comment: Correct for a POST, but you can still get the data submitted via GET .

Answer (score 0):

If you have submitted the page, then you have to get the form data using PHP.
Here is a tutorial that should help: http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-form.html

But **if** you decide to test jQuery, you can use this:

```
jQuery('#submit').live('click', function() 
{
  var form_data = jQuery("#data_form").serialize();  

  //Save data
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: siteURL +"/path/to/php/file/jquery.php",
    data: {formData : form_data,
    success: (function(data) {
      //data is whatever you return from jquery.php
      //I use json for return data
      alert('Data has been saved');
    }),
    dataType: 'json'
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getUrlInfo() {                 
  var data = window.location.search.substring(1).split("&");
  //returns an array of strings containing the params and their values   
  // data = [ "param=value","param=value","param=value"]

  var params1Array = data[0].substring(0).split("=");              
  //Splits the first string element at the "=" symbol and 
  //returns an array with the param and value 
  //param1Array = ["param","value"]

  var param1Value = param1Array[1].replace("+", " ");
  //Gets the value from the second element in the param1Array
  //Replaces the spaces, if any, in the second element, 
  //which is the value of the url param

   var param2Array = data[1].substring(0).split("="); 
    //Repeat steps for the second param element,in the url params data array 
    var param2Value= param2Array[1].replace("+", " ");
      return {
            param1Value,
            param2Value
         }
      };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The submitted data (either POST or GET) is proccesed on the server side. Javascript runs on the client-side so you can't access the variables from the page receiving the form request.
But you can access them before the post using the input field id (specially to check the input values before sending them).

Comment: Not true: the GET data is submitted as part of the URL, and is thus accessible via plain JavaScript